# How can I find out why a package was installed?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

How can I find out why a particular package was installed?

- Is it part of the default installation?
- Was it specified manually, or was it chosen automatically to meet dependencies?
- Which packages are dependent on it?
- When was it installed?