# How do I fix "sorry, a problem occurred while installing software blcr-dkms"?

Tags: installation, kernel, dkms

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running smoothly without any problems. Until recently, I have been receiving this pop-up stating

`sorry, a problem occurred while installing software Package: blcr-dkms`

Ubuntu keeps running fine. I don't know if there is really anything wrong.

In the case that everything is fine, how do I remove these messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge blcr-dkms
sudo apt-get install blcr-dkms
```

Comment: It's a good idea to `sudo apt-get update` first. Also, purging and installation can be done in one command (and this makes sure the installation package is available before purging): `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install blcr-dkms`

Comment: I am afraid it did not work work. I also checked the installation log for the error and at the end of the file was this: configure: error: --with-linux argument '3.2.0-25-generic-pae' is neither a kernel version string nor a full path
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/config-stamp] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic-pae'

Comment: @user65314 Please edit your question to include the complete and exact text from the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug filed on this:

"blcr kernel module failed to build with kernel 3.0 : configure: error: --with-linux argument '3.0-x' is neither a kernel version string nor a full path" https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blcr/+bug/804943

Someone suggests just removing the package. (Perhaps first check why the package is installed -- [Can I see why a package is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed))

Comment: The package was Paraview, which was installed along with OpenFOAM. Which results that I do not need anymore. So I just removed bclr-dkms

Comment: If your problem solved, please answer your question and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!