# What does it mean that python-keyring "suggests" python-kde4?

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cache

I have a pending update for "Get Hot New Stuff" for the KDE Platform (`libknewstuff2-4`).

I don't recall installing anything with KDE dependencies (I'm using vanilla Ubuntu), so I tried to figure out why it's there.

I found that I can use

`apt-cache rdepends --installed libknewstuff2-4`

to find installed packages that depend on this. This leads me to the package `python-kde4`. Upstream of this package are: `python-qt4` and `python-keyring`.

At this point, things get hard to follow. qt-4 seems to have a circular dependency back to `python-kde4`. I think I can trace `-keyring` back to `bzr`, but I also see `python-crypto` upstream from `-keyring`. `-crypto` has more rdepends than I care to investigate...

Is there a better way to understand what's going on here?
Alternatively, does it make sense that I'm getting kde libraries based on a package that isn't KDE specific (like bzr)?

EDIT: Using `aptitude why` as recommended below seems to automate what I manually did with `apt-cache`:

```
$ aptitude why libknewstuff2-4 
i   bzr                 Depends    python-bzrlib (>= 2.6.0+bzr6593-1ubuntu1.1)
i A python-bzrlib       Recommends python-launchpadlib                        
i A python-launchpadlib Depends    python-keyring (>= 0.5)                    
i A python-keyring      Suggests   python-kde4                                
i A python-kde4         Depends    libknewstuff2-4 (>= 4:4.13.3)
```

Although I'm not sure what the "Recommends" and "Suggests" states mean. The man page says:

> Note that the dependency that aptitude produced in this case is only a
>   suggestion. This is because no package currently installed on this
>   computer depends on or recommends the ... package; if a stronger
>   dependency were available, aptitude would have displayed it.

So what does it really mean that python-keyring "suggests" python-kde4, and do I have a choice in pulling in this "dependency"?

Comment: Try `aptitude why` - it might give simpler results.

Comment: A suggests type dependency is the weakest type, it should be safe to remove.

Comment: @muru I ended up apt-get removing `bzr` based on what I saw in `aptitude why`. When I reinstalled it, it didn't pull in the "Suggested" packages and so therefore solved my problem. Please repost `aptitude why` as an answer.

Comment: It's already an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed, and the question is sufficiently similar that I'll mark it as a duplicate instead.

Comment: You can remove "python-kde4" without problems. Is just a suggested package.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find out why this was installed would be to `zgrep libknewstuff2 /var/log/apt/*` (you may have to use sudo). The hits might give you some hints as to why this got installed...

Comment: I think that this points to pretty close to the time that I originally installed Ubuntu. Any way I can use that to help narrow this down?

Comment: Well, installation timestamps close to identical would perhaps have given a clue... But if it got installed initially then I guess it's not useful in your case.