# ImageMagick suddenly installed

Tags: software-center, imagemagick

I was taking a look at my installed programs, when I saw a program called `ImageMagick`, I took a look at it in the Ubuntu Software Center, and it's a program to manipulate images.

That's OK, but I never installed that! I saw that I installed that approx. 1 month ago (May 25).

Just to be sure, did it came with an update or something like that?

Comment: FYI ImageMagick is a collection of programs and a library to manipulate images. The programs included are command-line, so they are typically used as dependencies for other programs. You likely installed something that depends on ImageMagick for an operation such as scaling or cropping.

Comment: So... it appeared like Magick? (Sorry. Couldn't resist.)

Comment: @jpmc26 How I coudn't think about this joke?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I see why a package is installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In addition to the above answer, you can have some checks.

From your Software Center you can know the recent installed or updated apps.

And you can know which apps have `imagemagick` as dependency so you can know which app had installed it.

```
apt-cache rdepends imagemagick
```

sample output:

```
Reverse Depends:
  inkscape
    graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
  formatjunkie
    graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
  playonlinux
    graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
  lives
    graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
  variety
    graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
 |ejabberd
    graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
  imagemagick:i386
 |qt4-qmlviewer
```

From `man apt-get`

```
rdepends pkg...
           rdepends shows a listing of each reverse dependency a package has.
```

Comment: :) I think, that's a better answer than my answer. +1

Comment: @Maythux I just saw many programs that I use in the list (like Libre office). Well, now that makes sense. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Nori-chan you are welcome friend

Answer (score 4):

Imagemagick was installed, because it is required by another program that you recently (May 25) installed.

No voodoo, no magic. **;)**