# Optimize apt dependency list

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to keep my system clean of various headers and -dev packages. Sometimes I see in many tutorials, setup guides `apt install` string which includes multiple package names, where many of those packages are dependencies of some other packages mentioned in the string already. Even if I skip those names, they will be installed anyway (as dependencies).

But the problem is by explicitly mentioning these packages in `apt-get install` string, these are being marked as "manually installed" and thus cannot be removed automatically (with `apt-get autoremove`) when the main package is no more needed.

For example:

```
apt install gawk m4 libglib2.0-dev libwxbase3.0-dev wx3.0-headers libwxgtk3.0-dev
```

Here, the `wx3.0-headers` is an automatic dependency of `libwxbase3.0-dev`, so it is not needed to be in the install command, and I suspect that `libwxgtk3.0-dev` includes them both and maybe `libglib2.0-dev` too.

So is there a way to detect these excess dependencies automatically to build a minimal `apt` command that is needed to get everything set?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic dependency? will you explain?

Comment: What is the harm done by including the dependency in the `apt` command, even when it would be installed anyway? The package won't be installed twice, or even downloaded twice.

Comment: @Anwar updated question

Comment: @Jos the package won't be removed automatically when not needed.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik Can you join [this room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44272/helpline) to discuss it. It's still a bit unclear to me

Comment: @anatolytechtonik This is an old one but might be what you are after: http://askubuntu.com/q/5636/57576

Comment: @andrew.46 check these dependencies manually is not an option. I hoped that some automatic tool exists.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik Ah yes, good point.