# Does openjdk-7-jdk depend on systemd?

Tags: apt, systemd, jdk, openjdk, aptitude

I'm trying to install `openjdk-7-jdk` on Ubuntu Trusty (with `apt` or `aptitude`), but it seems to depend on `systemd`, which I'd like to avoid. But also, I can't see `systemd` in the output of `debtree` or `apt-rdepends`. Why is that so? Does `openjdk-7-jdk` depend on `systemd` or not?

To give you the bigger picture, I'm provisioning a server. And it all happens when installing `elasticsearch`. It wants `java`, and `java` wants `systemd`. But after installing `systemd`, it can't enable `elasticsearch`, since it comes with init script, not systemd unit file. It sees `systemctl` and supposes it's to be used, not `service`.

**UPD** It doesn't need `systemd` until I do `apt update`. Before `apt update`:

```
# apt-cache policy openjdk-7-jdk
openjdk-7-jdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

# apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

After `apt update`:

```
# apt-cache policy openjdk-7-jdk
openjdk-7-jdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

# apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 204-5ubuntu20.20
  Version table:
     204-5ubuntu20.20 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Aren't they switching Ubuntu Trusty to `systemd`?

Also, the OS is running in lxc container, but I doubt that has to do with this. And it's a fresh install, so to say. I create container, log in, `apt update`, `apt install openjdk-7-jdk`, and it wants `systemd`.

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

And nothing in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: If you are provisioning a server, why not provision it with Ubuntu 16.04? Since it has `systemd`, that would solve your problem as well has having a longer support lifespan remaining than Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty).

Comment: The software to be run on the server is yet to be updated to be able to run on newer Ubuntu. For now we decided to stick with Ubuntu Trusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, `systemd` was pulled in as a recommendation, namely:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/openjdk-7-jdk
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/openjdk-7-jre
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libgtk-3-0
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libcolord1 (recommends colord)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/colord
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/policykit-1
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libpam-systemd
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/systemd-services

And here we can see the difference in behavior between LXC containers and physical servers. LXC containers usually come with basic set of packages. Things like these might be missing: `man`, `less`, `ping`, `vi`, `curl`.

The point being, [`systemd-services`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/systemd-services) depends on `systemd` or `systemd-shim` (>= 3). After fresh Ubuntu install you usually have `systemd-shim` installed. So installing `openjdk-7-jdk` doesn't pull in `systemd` package.

In case of LXC container, neither of those two is installed, so when asking `apt` to install `openjdk-7-jdk` it choses the first one: `systemd` package.

One way to fight it is install `systemd-shim` before installing `openjdk-7-jdk`. Which I like more, since the other one (`apt install --no-install-recommends openjdk-7-jdk`) might reject some useful dependencies.

See [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2016-December/288665.html) mailing list [discussion](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2017-January/288707.html) for more details.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866617/how-do-i-trace-back-which-dependency-chain-leads-to-some-particular-package/868152#868152) for details on tracing back dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [package of openjdk-7-jdk available for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openjdk-7-jdk). 14.04 is based on Upstart, not trusty. Therefore, the package must run 14.04 without the systemd init system.

The systemd package you referring to is [systemd from trusty-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/systemd). From that page, you can [download and review the packages that Debian added to make the package.](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_204-5ubuntu20.20.debian.tar.xz)

In compressed archive, you'll find this in the README file:

> systemd can be installed alongside sysvinit and will not change the
>   behaviour of the system out of the box.  This is intentional.  To test
>   systemd, add:
>
> ```
> init=/bin/systemd
> ```
>
> to the kernel command line and then rebooting, or install the
>   systemd-sysv package.

systemd provides a number of packages, of which OpenJDK must depend on one. You can confirm that the `systemd-sysv` package is not a dependency.

I'm aware of no circumstance in which installing standard packages on Ubuntu 14.04 would result in switching the system to use systemd as the init system without the user explicitly opting in.

Should your 14.04 system somehow end up with both Upstart and systemd installed, you can interrupt the boot process, enter the grub menu and modify the kernel command line to add `init=/sbin/upstart` to boot it back with Upstart, and then uninstall or change what you need to.

---

To solve the problem with elasticsearch not starting, use http://packages.ubuntu.com to find a version of elasticsearch from `trusty` or earlier, and copy the "init.d" script from there. This fix will persist through upgrades of elasticsearch that you may do.

I think you are caught an odd state because even though you are using 14.04, some package maintainers are moving to expect `systemd`. I don't think you're going to find a better fix than the workaround like that.

Comment: Feel free to ask questions about my environment. And check out my question please, I've added more details.

Comment: [Here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/systemd) you go, `systemd` in `trusty-updates`.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: `You can confirm that the systemd-sysv package is not a dependency.` I see the only way (if systemd-sysv is not installed yet): `apt install openjdk-7-jdk` and see if it wants to install it. As I said earlier, I failed to find the dependency chain that leads to systemd package. Can you help here? Then, I'm not saying that my system switched to systemd. I'm saying that after installing openjdk-7-jdk ansible sees /bin/systemctl and tries to use it to enable elasticsearch. But elasticsearch doesn't come with systemd unit file. It comes with init script. And ansible fails.

Comment: Answer updated to deal with failing elasticsearch.

Comment: If Ansible is using the presence of /bin/systemctl to decide that it's on a `systemd` based system, that's a bug, since systemctl can be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 when `systemd` is not the init system. [Here are better ways to detect the init system in use](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell)

Comment: See also [Can I see why a package is installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed) to review the dependencies.

Comment: @MakrStosberg I didn't look into finding a way to detect init system. But if you did, you can take a look at [what ansible does](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/service.py#L434-L456) and file a report, if you care. Although it doesn't seem there's a fullproof way. Also, this is how [I](http://askubuntu.com/questions/866617/how-do-i-trace-back-which-dependency-chain-leads-to-some-particular-package/868152#868152) managed to trace back the dependency. And, I seem to have found a workaround: install `systemd-shim` beforehand, see my answer.