# How do I trace back which dependency chain leads to some particular package?

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, systemd, openjdk

For example, `openjdk-7-jdk` in trusty depends on `systemd`. How do I figure out dependency chain that leads to `systemd`? I tried `debtree openjdk-7-jdk` and `apt-rdepends openjdk-7-jdk`, but they don't list `systemd`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `apt depends --recurse openjdk-7-jdk`, but it will produce tons of output.

Comment: @ByteCommander Sorry, I didn't state it clearly. I'm running Ubuntu Trusty. And that's probably why your command gives: `E: Command line option --recurse is not understood`. `debtree` and `apt-rdepends` don't have such an option. I believe they must recurse by default.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I failed was that `systemd` is pulled in as a recommendation. This way you can see the recommendations as well:

```
apt-rdepends openjdk-7-jdk --follow Depends,PreDepends,Recommends \
    --show Depends,PreDepends,Recommends | grep systemd
```

The dependency chain is as follows:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/openjdk-7-jdk
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/openjdk-7-jre
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libgtk-3-0
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libcolord1 (recommends colord)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/colord
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/policykit-1
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libpam-systemd
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/systemd-services

Comment: Didn't know about the apt-rdepends package, very useful...