# How to keep grub from ever reinstalling itself

Tags: 16.04, apt, grub2, bootloader

I'm using the `refind` bootloader and never, ever want to use `grub`. Now and then, Ubuntu Xenial automatically pulls it in and I get a prompt about where to install the grub bootloader.[1] I explicitly don't want `grub` potentially mucking up my setup.

- how can I find out why grub is being summoned?
- how can I prevent it from ever being installed again?

[1] By 'it', I mean `grub-common`, `grub-gfxpayload-lists`, `grub-pc`, `grub-pc-bin`, `grub2-common`.

Comment: I presume there is a new version of grub and Ubuntu updates it. If so probably pinning grub at the current version will solve it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix nope, no `grub-*` is installed, then it's newly installed. See my answer for why (it's pulled in as recommended by the kernel image package). Pinning to `-1` has fixed it, but there were several blacklisting options along the way and I tried 3; only pinning worked, which still perplexes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2 2018-10-01:** got it. tl;dr is that `apt-mark hold grub-foo` (on all desired packages) was the ticket, but appears to have required manually calling on each package `apt dist-upgrade` was attempting to bring in.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold grub*
grub2 set on hold.
grub set on hold.
grub-common set on hold.

[... a bunch more packages ...]

grub-pc set on hold.
grub-legacy-doc set on hold.
grub2-common set on hold.
grub-gfxpayload-lists set on hold.
grub-pc-bin set on hold.
```

But right after...

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-6-base:i386 grub-common:i386 grub-gfxpayload-lists:i386 grub-pc:i386 grub-pc-bin:i386 grub2-common:i386 ...
```

Go figure. However, manually specifying the above `grub*` packages to `apt-mark hold` worked and `apt dist-upgrade` no longer pulls in grub.

Last comment is that I tried this in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/grub-blacklist`:

```
Package: grub*
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

That didn't work.

---

**Edit 2018-10-01:** this was not the solution... even with the setting in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove` below, `apt dist-upgrade` is still putting it forward to be installed. To be continued...

---

I think I may have answered both questions.

> how can I find out why grub is being summoned?

I'm most familiar with `pacman` on arch; looks like the equivalent to `pacman -Qi pkg` where you get a list of which packages require the named package. This was [one equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed) of that for ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed grub-pc
|linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic
    grub-pc:i386
```

So, the meta-package for the linux kernel pulls it in. If I had more time/inclination, I'd see if there was some set of packages to install directly vs. relying on this convenience package, but I don't care to do that at this time.

> how can I prevent it from ever being installed again?

In looking for how to blacklist in ubuntu, there were various options, but I settled on [this one](https://www.linux.com/blog/how-blacklist-packages-ubuntu) because it seemed the least weird/hokey:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove
{
  ...
  Never-MarkAuto-Sections
  {
    ...
    "grub*";
  };
};
```