# Multipass was installed without consent

Tags: multipass

I rebooted my machine after and this software was installed. I'm assuming it was from something I've updated, because I haven't installed anything.

Is this part of a new Ubuntu update or something? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Comment: "Without consent" seems highly unlikely. There is no nefarious plan to force Multipass on unsuspecting users. How exactly did you discover that it was installed?

Comment: Have a look at `history` and see what was typed and logged. "Is this part of a new Ubuntu update or something?" No. And nothing depends on it. Are you the only admin on this system? Maybe you installed something using a wildcard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I see why a package is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed)

Comment: @user535733 it started showing an indicator in the top bar.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm the only user. I never installed this or used a wildcard recently.

Comment: @muru it looks like it was never installed with `apt`, so that doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: Then where did you see it installed? Is it in the output of `snap list`?