# Why do I have TeXInfo installed all of a sudden?

Tags: 22.04

[image]

Running Ubuntu 22.04 fully up to date, I noticed an app I didn't install myself called `TeXInfo` is now on my system. I assume it got pulled in recently as a dependency from another app or possibly something that got pulled in during an `apt upgrade`, but I'm not entirely sure.

(1) Does anyone know why or where this got added from and (2) if it's safe to remove or not? Please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Related: [Can I see why a package is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed)

Comment: Did you recently install LaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
apt-cache rdepends texinfo
```

will show you which packages require `texinfo` to be installed. This will make clear why this package now is on your system.